# juniper: j2320 vs ex3200

Tags: juniper

I'm looking for a router for our network. Currently I'm between these two Juniper devices:

J2320 (router)
http://www.juniper.net/us/en/products-services/routing/j-series/j2320

ex3200 (L3 switch):
http://www.juniper.net/us/en/products-services/switching/ex-series/ex3200

The price I've been given is almost the same. Both routers a BGP capable. Could anyone advice, which one should I go for?

Comment: -1 for telling us absolutely nothing upon which to base a recomendation. You say "Both routers a BGP capable" but haven't even told us whether that's something you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to use these for. You mention BGP - if you would like to hold a full BGP table, the EX3200 will not fit:

```
IPv4 Unicast / Multicast Routes 
16,000 / 8,000
```

At the moment, a full feed has about 400,000 IPv4 routes.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. We have an AS and two providers. But currently I only receive default routes from both peers (not full tables). So I guess both models I'm looking at will do fine. Apart from BGP peering with two provides I don't really need any special features from the router.

Comment: No problem with just default routes, then. In general, switches (and L3-switches) are faster than routers, but less flexible.